# Как подключить FTP сервер к Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, ftp

У меня есть некое приложение файлообменника, и для передачи файла на сервер я пытаюсь использоваться retrofit. Вот код:

```
public void upload(Uri uri) {
        File originalFile = new File(uri.getPath());

        RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(uri)),
                originalFile
        );
        MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", originalFile.getName(), filePart);

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        FileUploadService client = retrofit.create(FileUploadService.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = client.upload(file);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "DONE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("DONE!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "FAILED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("FAILED!");
            }
        });
    }
```

У меня имеется ftp сервер с доменным именем, логином и паролем. Что мне нужно написать в baseUrl, чтобы Retrofit подключился к этому серверу? И если это вообще невозможно, то что мне следует использовать вместо него?

Comment: Retrofit разработан именно для HTTP, для FTP придется искать что-то другое.

Comment: ftp4j вам в помощь :)